# publish web application on windows server 2008 to access through internet

Tags: php, web-applications, windows-server-2008, publish

I have created a web application using php and mysql and it is working fine on the local server, operating system of which is windows server 2008R2, and is accessible throughout network. I want to be able to access it through internet using a custom host name. How can I manage to do so?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to run it from within your network or have it hosted on the internet?

Comment: @Trevor I want it to be hosted on my local server in my network, meanwhile being able to access it via internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do three things. One is a name. Cheapest, easiest and most flexible is a host name within one of the many free dynamic dns providers. Just google `free dynamic dns`. You then need to either configure your router to tell the relevant dns provider your ip address as it often changes or follow the instructions that are available from the DNS provider on setting up a script or application that tells the provider your ip address on a regular basis.

Then you need to configure port forwarding to map port 80 and possible port 443 if you are using https to your windows server. How to do this depends on your specific router so it’s time to read the manual. If you get stuck with this part, best site to be asking questions on this area is https://superuser.com/ , another stackexchange site that your stackoverflow login should work on too.

Exposing your system to the internet does have it’s security issues. Now more than ever you should be maintaining your security software along with looking at some form of hack detection software (google `intrusion detection software`). You may be able to find out other things you can do at https://security.stackexchange.com/ but do read the sites help so you know what and how to ask questions.